# Proper way to declare inline function which returns int

Tags: c, visual-c++, inline

The following code

```
inline int read_int()
{
    return 5;
}
```

resulted in error: `expected a ';'`

I have tried to write the above code in a seperate file from my project, but the error is still there. Which is strange, as I saw several programs uses such a function.

Is there anyway to fix that problem? What could be the solution?
I am also using Visual Studio, and programming for CodeChef which requires speed.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, it's better to leave inlining to the compiler/optimizer. I never used `inline` so far and analyzing the assembly output of e.g. `clang -O3`, I found a lot of functions inlined. Not inlining a simple constant return would be brainless ...

Comment: @basd dsasda It seems that the compiler you are using does not support the inline specifier or you need to set an option of the compiler to switch on the supporting.

Comment: @basd dsasda As far as I know MS VS does not support C99 where this specifier was introduced.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's correct. MSVC conforms to C89, supporting just a little subset of C99. But again, if your compiler doesn't do a good job at inlining *without* explicit `inline` specifier ... throw it away and use a real compiler.

Comment: You can use `__inline` with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently gcc is perfectly happy with functions declared as `inline int()`.

However, clang will reject these for some reason. If the function only applies to the current file, then declaring it as static will get around the issue.

The following code compiles and runs in both gcc and clang:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int read_int() {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  x = read_int();
  printf("int=%d\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

### Edit:

I found [some documentation on clang's behaviour](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline), which explains the situation.

Briefly, clang adheres to the C99 standard, where an inline function is regarded as an alternative version of another function that is used when the code isn't optimized.  Static inline functions are always used, thus avoiding the problem.

Another alternative is to compile with optimization (even `-O1`), which will cause the compiler to use the inline version of a function instead of searching for the non-inline version (which isn't there).

Comment: I don't think OP is using gcc or clang. Visual studio maybe, or some other oddball compiler.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Beats me. The clang documentation says this should cause an `undefined symbol` error. If the OP isn't using clang, then I guess there are other C99 compilers that will behave in a similar way, albeit with different error handling/

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Undefined symbol means that the compiler requires an external definition of the function. If you will use extern instead of the static then the program will be compiled.

Comment: @user3386109 Visual Stuido, and what do you mean by "oddball"?

Comment: @user3386109 explain that please.

Comment: @basddsasda Just fix your question to specify that you're using Visual Studio.